# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(Ljava/lang/Object; ...) when trying to execute tests in Selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, nosuchmethoderror

After upgrading the Selenium version from 3.141.59 to 4.6.0, I got the below error when trying to execute test cases.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;
```

After spending some time on the internet I was able to understand that this happened due to ImmutableMap.of() only accepting max.10 parameters, but when executing a test it tries to pass 12 parameters underneath (at the test layer I didn't use such a function anywhere, so I think this is used by some kind of library). So, then I applied the below workarounds.

- Upgraded the guava version from 23.0 to 31.0.1-jre.
- Upgraded the guava version from 23.0 to 31.1-jre.
- Add the `io.github.bonigarcia` dependency version 5.0.3.
- Add the `io.github.bonigarcia` dependency version 5.1.0.

But none of these helped to resolve this issue.
Then I tried to delete existing ImmutableMap files from the .m2 folder, but there isn't such `com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap` path in the .m2 folder.

*Please note that I'm not allowed to downgrade the current Selenium version since I'm working on my company test framework*

Few other things currently I'm using.

- Chrome version - 109.0.5414.120
- Java version - 1.8.0_341

Please can anyone help me to overcome this issue? Really appreciate any help!

Comment: The given location `com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap` is not in the repository it's inside a jar file inside the repository... (guava...)...I would check which dependency the selenium version is using...

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;
```

...implies that *NoSuchMethod* was raised for `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;` which indicates it might be corrupted or there is some incompatibility between the version of the binaries you are using specifically with the **guava** *version*.

---

### Solution

As you were using *Selenium v3.141.59* earlier first you need to remove all the previous jars from the project then,

- Either download the new *`selenium-java-4.8.0.zip`* file, extract the jars and add them one by one to your project.
- Or download the new *`selenium-server-4.8.0.jar`* file and add it to your project.

Incase you are using [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) you can delete the **`.m2`** folder from your system and perform the following maven commands:

```
>mvn build
>mvn test
```

Comment: Hi @undetected Selenium, I added Selenium 4.8.0 and built as you mentioned, then I got the "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Rotatable" error. Then I added Appium (V8.3.0) newly to the pom, and after that, I got the same previous "com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of()" error. Is there a different way to overcome this issue?